# Start a process in python once an hour

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Currently, I'm writing a server to response requests in python, and I want to start another process to deal with data once an hour.

I only know that `multiprocessing` can create the process but I don't how to create it once an hour?

Comment: Did you try time.time() function?

Comment: I think the `subprocess` module might be more relevant than `multiprocessing`.

Comment: @qqvc no, I only know time.time() can get current time, do you mean starting another process according to time.time() % 3600 ?

Comment: What OS are out using? Foe Unix type systems (Linux, AIX, Solaris) you could use cron. For Windows systems, you could use the Windows task scheduler.

Comment: @DavidHarris using Linux

Comment: sleep(3600) will wait excatly 1 hour after your code.So isnt it your solution? You can define a function with it and use it whenever you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sched? The [Sched module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) defines a class which implements a general purpose event scheduler:

Answer (score 0):

Let me explain you my point.

```
while True:
    ~~codes # this is codes you want to continue once an hour
    sleep(3600)
```

> This while loop is infinit now, once its process your codes, it will
>   wait 3600seconds, then it will process it again, and it will wait 3600
>   seconds again till you stop the while loop.

So for example, if you want it 5hours:

```
x=0
while x<5:
    ~~codes # this is codes you want to continue once an hour
    sleep(3600)
    x+=1
```

Comment: during sleep, how do I handle requests?

Comment: I dont know your codes excatly so I cant make a comment right now

Comment: also you said you want it once an hour?

Comment: the `while` loop is blocking -- unless you've threaded/forked before this point and gone asycnronous, your application won't be able to do anything once the interpreter hits this loop.  you'd likely be better served using your OS's scheduler to run a worker application.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to start another process,use a single programme to handle Hourly requests.You can use a scheduler called CRON in linux to do that.

type this to check if any croontabs available already

$ sudo crontab -l
If it says no crontab installed then add one.

$sudo crontab -e

It then will ask you to chose editor,chose any editor you prefer,my choice is nano.

next add cron scheduling command to that file.For your problem if programme is test.py,then

add following line in the editor opened.

"* */1 * * * python /path_to_test.py/test.py"

Path is where your program file lies.Your programme will wake up each hour and handle the requests.for more details on cron visit this page.http://impythonist.wordpress.com/2014/11/13/how-to-wake-up-a-python-script-while-you-are-in-a-sound-sleep/

If you require multiprocessing capability,go for  APScheduler.

https://apscheduler.readthedocs.org/en/latest/